# EF Code First - Invalid column name

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Im getting an error "Invalid column name 'FeeLevel_LevelId' which makes absolutely no sense considering all properties are simple types and there is no FeeLevel nor a LevelId object in this object.

So my context is:

```
  public partial class FeesDbContext : DisconnectedEntityContext
    {

        public DbSet<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }

        public DbSet<FeeLevel> FeeLevels { get; set; }

        public DbSet<FeeLevelDetail> FeeLevelDetails { get; set; }

        public DbSet<FeeType> FeeTypes { get; set; }

        public DbSet<MemberFeeDiscountLevel> MemberFeeDiscountLevels { get; set; }

        public FeesDbContext()
            : base("FeesDb") { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FeeLevelMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FeeLevelDetailMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FeeTypeMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CurrencyMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MemberFeeDiscountLevelMap());
        }

        public static void ApplyChanges<TEntity>(TEntity root)
                    where TEntity : class, IObjectWithState
        {
            using (var context = new FeesDbContext())
            {
                context.Set<TEntity>().Add(root);
                foreach (var entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries<IObjectWithState>())
                {
                    IObjectWithState stateInfo = entry.Entity;
                    entry.State = ConvertState(stateInfo.State);
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
}
```

The POCO is:

```
public partial class MemberFeeDiscountLevel : AbstractState
    {

        public long MemberFeeDiscountLevelId { get; set; }
        public System.Guid MemberId { get; set; }
        public short MemberAsType { get; set; }
        public long FeeDiscountLevelId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime FeeDiscountLevelAppliedDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FeeDiscountLevelExpiresDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> FallbackFeeDiscountLevelId { get; set; }
        public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastModified { get; set; }


        public MemberFeeDiscountLevel(ObjectState state) : base(state) { }

        public MemberFeeDiscountLevel()
        {
        }
    }
```

It's mapping is:

```
  public class MemberFeeDiscountLevelMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MemberFeeDiscountLevel>
    {
        public MemberFeeDiscountLevelMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.MemberFeeDiscountLevelId);

            this.Ignore(t => t.State);

            // Properties
            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("MemberFeeDiscountLevel");
            this.Property(t => t.MemberFeeDiscountLevelId).HasColumnName("MemberFeeDiscountLevelId");
            this.Property(t => t.MemberId).HasColumnName("MemberId");
            this.Property(t => t.MemberAsType).HasColumnName("MemberAsType");
            this.Property(t => t.FeeDiscountLevelId).HasColumnName("FeeDiscountLevelId");
            this.Property(t => t.FeeDiscountLevelAppliedDate).HasColumnName("FeeDiscountLevelAppliedDate");
            this.Property(t => t.FeeDiscountLevelExpiresDate).HasColumnName("FeeDiscountLevelExpiresDate");
            this.Property(t => t.FallbackFeeDiscountLevelId).HasColumnName("FallbackFeeDiscountLevelId");
            this.Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
            this.Property(t => t.LastModified).HasColumnName("LastModified");
        }
    }
```

The database table is:

[image]

and it has not relationships. Yet EF is generating the following SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[MemberFeeDiscountLevel]([MemberId], [MemberAsType], [FeeDiscountLevelId], [FeeDiscountLevelAppliedDate], [FeeDiscountLevelExpiresDate], [FallbackFeeDiscountLevelId], [UserId], [LastModified], [FeeLevel_LevelId])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, NULL)
SELECT [MemberFeeDiscountLevelId]
FROM [dbo].[MemberFeeDiscountLevel]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [MemberFeeDiscountLevelId] = scope_identity()',N'@0 uniqueidentifier,@1 smallint,@2 bigint,@3 datetime2(7),@4 datetime2(7),@5 bigint,@6 uniqueidentifier,@7 datetime2(7),@8 int',@0='DAF771D1-079F-4743-B5C7-FD0FA1C63E19',@1=0,@2=1012,@3='2014-01-24 12:05:36.0608347',@4='2014-02-01 00:00:00',@5=1018,@6='EEDF2C83-2123-4B1C-BF8D-BE2D2FA26D09',@7='2014-01-24 12:05:36.0608347'
go
```

**UPDATE:**

Creating a new Fees2DbContext stripping out the other DbSets "fixes" the problem.... but I dont know why... none of these classes / sets are related to the class in question.

```
 public partial class Fees2DbContext : DisconnectedEntityContext
    {
        public DbSet<MemberFeeDiscountLevel> MemberFeeDiscountLevels { get; set; }

        public Fees2DbContext()
            : base("FeesDb") { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MemberFeeDiscountLevelMap());
        }

        public static void ApplyChanges<TEntity>(TEntity root)
                    where TEntity : class, IObjectWithState
        {
            using (var context = new Fees2DbContext())
            {
                context.Set<TEntity>().Add(root);
                foreach (var entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries<IObjectWithState>())
                {
                    IObjectWithState stateInfo = entry.Entity;
                    entry.State = ConvertState(stateInfo.State);
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
       public partial class FeeLevel : AbstractState
        {
            public FeeLevel()
            {
                this.FeeLevelDetails = new List<FeeLevelDetail>();
                this.MemberFeeDiscountLevels = new List<MemberFeeDiscountLevel>();
            }

            public long LevelId { get; set; }

            public string LevelName { get; set; }

            public int CurrencyId { get; set; }

            public System.DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

            public bool IsSystemOwned { get; set; }

            public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }

            public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }

            [ScriptIgnore]
            public virtual ICollection<FeeLevelDetail> FeeLevelDetails { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<MemberFeeDiscountLevel> MemberFeeDiscountLevels { get; set; }
        }

public class FeeLevelMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FeeLevel>
    {
        public FeeLevelMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.LevelId);

            this.Ignore(t => t.State);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.LevelId);
            // .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

            this.Property(t => t.LevelName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("FeeLevel");
            this.Property(t => t.LevelId).HasColumnName("LevelId");
            this.Property(t => t.LevelName).HasColumnName("LevelName");
            this.Property(t => t.CurrencyId).HasColumnName("CurrencyId");
            this.Property(t => t.LastModified).HasColumnName("LastModified");
            this.Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");

            // Relationships
            this.HasRequired(t => t.Currency)
                .WithMany(t => t.FeeLevels)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CurrencyId);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the `FeeLevel` entity have a collection of `MemberFeeDiscountLevel`s?

Comment: Yes it does, as per update 2 in response to your question. What is EF doing here? I dont get it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`FeeLevel.MemberFeeDiscountLevels` is a navigation property and it introduces a one-to-many relationship between `FeeLevel` and `MemberFeeDiscountLevel`: A `FeeLevel` can have many `MemberFeeDiscountLevels` which means at the same time that a `MemberFeeDiscountLevel` has a single `FeeLevel`. Although you don't have a navigation and foreign key property in `MemberFeeDiscountLevel` the database must have a foreign key in the `MemberFeeDiscountLevel` table in order to model this relationship. EF assumes a default FK name as "*related entity name+underscore+primary key name*" = `FeeLevel_LevelId`. Because your database table doesn't have this column you get the exception.

Comment: O.k so somewhere along the way the models have gotten out of sync which makes sense because I've been using Entity Framework Power tools to auto generate some code but have clearly missed an update somewhere. Thx.