# Entity Framework 6 - Invalid column name error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm getting an error message that contains the following:

```
Invalid column name 'ContentArticleHOA_Id'.
Invalid column name 'ContentArticleHOAsubdivision_Id'.
Invalid column name 'ContentArticleHOA_Id'.
Invalid column name 'TopTierDivisionHOA_Id'.
Invalid column name 'ContentArticleHOAsubdivision_Id'.
```

Here are some of my classes from the data model:

```
public partial class ContentArticleHOAsubdivision
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long ContentArticleId { get; set; }
    public short SubdivisionId { get; set; }

    public virtual ContentArticleHOA ContentArticleHOA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubdivisionHOA> SubdivisionsHOA { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubdivisionHOA
{
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte TopTierDivisionId { get; set; }

    public virtual TopTierDivisionHOA TopTierDivisionHOA { get; set; }
}

public partial class TopTierDivisionHOA
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I know this is something to do with EF trying to automatically create columns in order to link tables, however I'm not sure what it's basing this on and what I need to do to fix this.  If I use [ForeignKey("*className*")] before one of the static (non-navigation) properties in the model to specify the type that it's a foreign key for, I get no compiler error however I then get the following issue:

[Entity Framework 6 - foreign key issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672095/entity-framework-6-foreign-key-issue)

Comment: have you added these column in Database and then update your edmx in  visual studio...?

Comment: I'm using code first against an existing database - there is no .edmx.  I've manually created the tables/columns in the existing database.

Comment: ok.. then you run migration and it is successful? after you added properties in your code.?

Comment: It seems to be you add in code but due to some reasons columns are not added in Database. Invalid column is sign for it

Comment: I'm just building the code in Visual Studio - it builds fine.  I've manually created new database tables in the database.  I'm not doing anything to automatically build the changes in the DB.

Comment: That's why this error comes up...

Comment: Run the Update-Database –Verbose command in Package Manager Console.

Comment: I don't need the columns in the database - the tables already have Id fields that I want to map to - they are all simply named 'Id' in the relevant tables of the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57076/discussion-between-chris-halcrow-and-azhar-se-nextbridge).

Comment: Here is a similar issue explained http://stackoverflow.com/a/21321887/942855 by Slauma