# Entity Framework 6 - foreign key issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following model using EF6, where I'm trying to link a 'ContentArticleHOAsubdivision' entity to a 'SubdivisionHOA':

```
public partial class ContentArticleHOAsubdivision
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContentArticleHOA")]
    public long ContentArticleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SubdivisionsHOA")]
    public short SubdivisionId { get; set; }

    public virtual ContentArticleHOA ContentArticleHOA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubdivisionHOA> SubdivisionsHOA { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubdivisionHOA
{
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TopTierDivisionHOA")]
    public byte TopTierDivisionId { get; set; }

    public virtual TopTierDivisionHOA TopTierDivisionHOA { get; set; }
}
```

I get the error:

The foreign key component 'SubdivisionId' is not a declared property on type 'SubdivisionHOA'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.

The 'Id' property in SubdivisionHOA I'm trying to link on needs to be named 'Id' as that's the name of the actual column in the database, so I'm not sure what I need to do?

I've tried adding `[InverseProperty("Id")]` before the `[ForeignKey]` attributes but get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly the foreign key usage in EntityFramework seems like this:

```
public partial class ContentArticleHOAsubdivision
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<SubdivisionHOA> SubdivisionsHOAs { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubdivisionHOA
{
    public short Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public int ContentArticleHOAsubdivisionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContentArticleHOAsubdivisionId")]
    public virtual ContentArticleHOAsubdivision ContentArticleHOAsubdivision { get; set; }
}
```

Just based on your code, and I have discard some unknown stuffs.

Comment: Thanks, however 'ContentArticleHOAsubdivision' is an entity that represents a link between Content Articles and the 'subdivision' they belong to, so the 'Subdivision' doesn't need to have a property 'ContentArticleHOAsubdivision', as it doesn't need to know about the subdivisions that each Content Article belongs to.  In other words, this would be linking the wrong way round.

Comment: I understood what you would like to achieve, but as far as I know you have to set a property `ContentArticleHOAsubdivision` on `SubdivisionHOA` in order to connect them. From another perspective, maybe `ContentArticleHOAsubdivision` is not need for the entity, you can just make it as normal model, instead of store it a separate table (and let `SubdivisionHOA` know `ContentArticleHOA` directly). I don't know what exactly architecture your app has, but you have to do what I answered if you want to use EntityFramework.

Comment: This gives me an error Invalid column name 'ContentArticleHOAsubdivisionId', probably because the column doesn't exist in the SubdivisionHOA table in the database (it's correct that this column isn't in the SubdivisionHOA table)

Comment: Yes, you should adapt your table according your new entity model.