# EF6 Invalid Column Name Member_ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I've seen this error umpteen times and the cause is always due to a misconfigured Foreign Key setup.  In this case though, I just can't see the issue.

This test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Integration")]
    public void DataModelMemberNoteBuilds() {

        _context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

        var sut = _context.MemberNotes.FirstOrDefault();

        if (sut == null) {
            Assert.Inconclusive("return null");
        }

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(sut, typeof(Domain.Members.Note));

    }
```

Throws this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Member_ID'.

This is the POCO I'm building the model for:

```
public class Note
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int MemberID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public int EnteredByEmployeeID { get;  set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public bool IsActiveHotnote { get; set; }

    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
    public virtual Employees.Employee EnteredByEmployee { get; set; }

}
```

The table (not code-first generated):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MemberNotes](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [rv] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [MemberID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NoteTimestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [NoteEnteredByEmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NoteSubject] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [NoteBody] [nvarchar](2000) NOT NULL,
    [NoteIsActiveHotnote] [bit] NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC) WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberNotes] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [DateCreated]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberNotes] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [NoteTimestamp]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberNotes] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [NoteIsActiveHotnote]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberNotes]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([MemberID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Members] ([MemberID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberNotes]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([NoteEnteredByEmployeeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([EmployeeID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
    -- <<<<<<<<<<<<<< NOTE ON DELETE NO ACTION <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
GO
```

The model is being build like so:

```
        mb.Entity<Note>().ToTable("MemberNotes");
        mb.Entity<Note>().Property(x => x.Body).HasColumnName("NoteBody");
        mb.Entity<Note>().Property(x => x.EnteredByEmployeeID).HasColumnName("NoteEnteredByEmployeeID");
        mb.Entity<Note>().Property(x => x.IsActiveHotnote).HasColumnName("NoteIsActiveHotnote");
        mb.Entity<Note>().Property(x => x.Subject).HasColumnName("NoteSubject");
        mb.Entity<Note>().Property(x => x.Timestamp).HasColumnName("NoteTimestamp");
        mb.Entity<Note>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Member)
            .WithMany(x => x.Notes)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberID);
        mb.Entity<Note>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.EnteredByEmployee)
            .WithMany(x => x.EnteredMemberNotes)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.EnteredByEmployeeID);
```

The only two related entities are `Member` and `Employee`, which have `ICollection`s as so:

```
// Member.cs
public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; } 

// Employee.cs
public virtual ICollection<Members.Note> EnteredMemberNotes { get; set; }
```

EF Query ouput from the test (`_context.MembersNotes.FirstOrDefault()`):

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [c].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [c].[MemberID] AS [MemberID], 
    [c].[NoteTimestamp] AS [NoteTimestamp], 
    [c].[NoteEnteredByEmployeeID] AS [NoteEnteredByEmployeeID], 
    [c].[NoteSubject] AS [NoteSubject], 
    [c].[NoteBody] AS [NoteBody], 
    [c].[NoteIsActiveHotnote] AS [NoteIsActiveHotnote], 
    [c].[Member_ID] AS [Member_ID]
    FROM [dbo].[MemberNotes] AS [c]
```

Can anyone see where that `Member_ID` is coming from?  I'm at a loss.  Thanks

Comment: The SQL query simply cannot be generated from EF6. Smells like EF Core.

Comment: Could you try to decorate your `Member` property with `ForeignKey` [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @IvanStoev EF 6.1.3 to be exact.  Not sure why you say this query can't be generated from EF6 (it's a copy/paste from my output, and I'm pretty sure I'm not using EF Core).  Michael - no, I'd much rather keep everything FluentAPI driven rather than annotations.

Comment: Could it be that you're configuring an EF6 context, but you're actually using an EF-core context? This really isn't EF6-generated SQL from the SQL-Server query provider.

Comment: @GertArnold - I really don't think so.  I've never used EF Core, and this model builder/context is grouped up with a dozen other entities that I've been using for a few months without issue.  It's all contained within one "Data" project, and that project has two EF references (see link).  This is the same `_context` that all other working models/tests are from.  http://imgur.com/a/r7rLi

Comment: The error seems related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321573/ef-code-first-invalid-column-name

Comment: The EF6 queries use `ExtendN`, `ProjectN` etc. aliases. Anyway. Are you sure there is no other `ICollection<Note>` inside your `Member` class? Or class derived from `Member` inside the same assembly?

Comment: @IvanStoev - if I add criteria to that query (`_context.MemberNotes.Where(x => x.ID == 1234).FirstOrDefault();` as opposed to (`_context.MemberNotes.FirstOrDefault();`), I get the usual Extents aliases.  Must be a shortened output syntax based on not having criteria (which would never really be a use case in production).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

My Member.cs class has a public read-only property that returns a `List<Note>` based on filtered content in `ICollection<Note>`

```
    public List<Note> Hotnotes {
        get
        {
            if (Notes == null) {
                return new List<Note>();
            }
            return Notes.Where(x => x.IsActiveHotnote).OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I neglected to tell EF to ignore this property.  It's reading the type and picking up the property as an additional relation/navigation property.

Putting this into the model builder fixes the problem:

```
mb.Entity<Member>().Ignore(x => x.Hotnotes);
```

Thanks for looking, hopefully this helps some other poor sod someday.

Comment: Cool. So I was right in my last comment *Are you sure there is no other `ICollection<Note>` inside your Member class?* :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Indeed you were!  Post an answer and I'll be happy to give you credit (I should have posted the full Member class, but I thought the question too long to begin with, and had forgotten how touchy seemingly unrelated properties could be...)

Comment: Hehe, it happens to all of us sometimes :) You answer is enough, no credit is needed, I'm glad that the issue is resolved. Happy coding.